# Dropbox Core API users limit

Tags: android, api, dropbox

I'm building an Android app using the Dropbox Core API.

I'm still using Developer Mode as I'm writing the app and in the console I can see there's a limit of 100 users for the API.

Will it be unlocked once I apply for the public use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the user limit will be removed when you apply for public use.

Answer (score 1):

When you want your app to be used by every user you would have to apply for "production mode" for your app.
please get the link below, and there you change your setting.

[Apply for production mode your app](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps/info/9mme9plibstwejq)

Answer (score 1):

- 1 access your app [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/apps)
- 2 Settings
- 3 Development users
- If status is only you
- --> 4 Enable additional users
- else --> 4 If you'd like to link more than 500 users, please apply for production status. More detail at [Dropbox
  Document](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/developer-guide#production-approval)